# Как в URL заменить метод GET через .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

Как в URL заменить метод GET через .htaccess для следующего примера?

Дан адрес:

> temp-name.local/index.php?page=authentication

Необходимо, чтобы получилось:

> temp-name.local/authentication

Я делал через `RewriteRule ^(.*)index/(.*)$ $1index?$2`, но так пишет ошибку.

Как решить эту задачу?

Comment: Какую ошибку пишет? И кто?

Comment: Что типа "Object not found! Error 404!", но это из-за того, что я в htaccess никогда не работал ))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такую задачу можно решить добавив в `.htaccess` следующее:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([^/d]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA]
```

Comment: Проверил! Работает! Спасибо Вам!